# How to get Group & Child item on ExpandableListView using getter & setter method

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hey guys I am trying to get items on `ExpandableListView`'s `setOnGroupClickListener` & `setOnChildClickListener` but not getting it's item.

Here is my code :

Group.java

```
public class Group {

private String Name;
private ArrayList<Child> Items;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public ArrayList<Child> getItems() {
    return Items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<Child> items) {
    Items = items;
}
}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child {
private String Name;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
}
```

ExpandListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Group> groups;

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv.setText(group.getName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);

    tv.setText(child.getName().toString());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "http://ec2-52-40-135-171.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/shop-cart/backend/web/api/category";

private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;

ArrayList<Group> list;
ArrayList<Child> ch_list;
Group gru;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);

    list = new ArrayList<Group>();


    makejsonobjreq();


    ExpandList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, list.get(i) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });

    ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + ExpAdapter.getChild(i, i1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void makejsonobjreq() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("RES", String.valueOf(response));


            try {
                JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject("data");
                Log.e("data RES", jo.toString());

                Log.e("dataLENGTH", String.valueOf(jo.length()));

                //CHNGE NEEDED ==> REPLACE 2 WITH jo.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                    gru = new Group();
                    gru.setName(jo.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i + 1)).getJSONArray("parent").getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));

                    Log.e("gru", gru.getName());
                    ch_list = new ArrayList<Child>();

                    JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i + 1)).getJSONArray("child");
                    Log.e("child ARRAY", String.valueOf(ja));
                    Log.e("child LENGTH", String.valueOf(ja.length()));

                    for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++) {

                        Child ch = new Child();
                        ch.setName(ja.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
                        ch_list.add(ch);

                        Log.e("CHILD NAME", "VAL OF J  " + j + "   " + ja.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
                    }
                    gru.setItems(ch_list);
                    list.add(gru);
                }

                ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your problem you are facing???

Comment: i cant get group item or child item on its click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your item into the view as a tag in `getChildView` or `getGroupView` like this:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    // keep your code
    // set item as a tag
    convertView.setTag(child);
    return convertView;
}
```

then you can get the item in the callback like

```
ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {
        // get tag from view, it will be better if your check the object type.
        Child child = (Child)view.getTag();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: WOW man.. you saved my day.. its working like charm.. Thank you for the help. I am giving you upvote and answer as accepted.

Comment: can you please explain me the concept that what had happened and how this solution is tricked.? why we need to add tag? @Asslstne

Comment: @Chirayu it is just like a setter & getter method, you can set an object into a View and get it back when you what. Because many callback listeners in Android will pass you the View instead of the data, so it is common to put some data into a view as a tag if the data and the View have strong connection.